# ImageView.ScaleType.FitXY not works in code

Tags: android, android-imageview

I don't know why scaleType not works for this ImageView. widthGrayBlock is correct, I checked it with black background. ImageView has correct width and height but image resource doesn't fit it. Thank you.

```
        ImageView gray = new ImageView(mParentActivity);
        gray.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        gray.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                widthGrayBlock, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(marginLeft, 0, 5, 0);
        progressLayout.addView(gray, 1, params);
        gray.setImageResource(R.drawable.schedule_bar_gray);
        //gray.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your xml

```
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

it's worked for me when i had a problem.

Comment: why is so important to be in code? You can set this only in xml and all other in code.

Comment: I'm surprised but you are right. scaleType works in xml but not works in code